# text-overflow: ellepsis not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this table that I want to spruce up a bit, but am having no succes despite the solutions I have found all across Stackoverflow.

I am using PHP to echo the table, with some some data from an SQL db.
[image: This is the table]

As you can see in the bottom right, the browser does not see the styling I have added for overflow etc..

Below is the html:

```
<div class="span9">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="btn" href="records.php">Add New Record</a><br><br>
        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed" border="1" cellpadding="10">
            <tbody>
                <tr> 
                    <th class="th.id"><a href="?orderby=id">ID</a></th> 
                    <th class="th.status"><a href="?orderby=status">Status</a></th> 
                    <th class="th.cust"><a href="?orderby=customer">Customer</a></th> 
                    <th class="th.prod"><a href="?orderby=product">Product</a></th> 
                    <th class="th.ord">Order Number</th> 
                    <th class="th.ret">Return Code</th> 
                    <th class="th.dop"><a href="?orderby=dop">Date of Purchase</a></th> 
                    <th class="th.sn">Serial Number</th> 
                    <th class="th.prob">Problem Description</th> 
                    <th class="th.rep">Repair Description</th> 
                    <th class="th.part">Parts Used</th> 
                    <th class="th.com">Comments</th> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p><a href="records.php?id=1">1</a></p></td>
                    <td><p>Error!</p></td>
                    <td><p>Jesse</p></td>
                    <td><p>Fuse</p></td>
                    <td><p></p></td>
                    <td><p></p></td>
                    <td><p></p></td>
                    <td><p>ComicalCanary</p></td>
                    <td><p>Not enough sand</p></td>
                    <td><p>Added sand</p></td>
                    <td><p>sand 10kg</p></td>
                    <td><p>I want to put a lot of content into this, to see how far this will go in stretching the table.</p></td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And below is my css, i'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7, but this is what I'm adding:

```
.table {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.table td {
    width: 120px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

And even the width: 120px; is not even working...
Any clues anyone?

Comment: Apologies, edited.

Comment: try this with > p,    .table td > p { ... }

Comment: consult with a doctor xD - It's `ellipsis` - not `epilepsis`, which is a medical condition.

Comment: Hahaha, I'm so dumb xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move your `ellipsis` styling down to the `p` tag.

```
.table p {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/koralarts/y6q3uvkL/1/

Answer (score 0):

Set the max-width on your td css or put a div inside the td with the ellipsis on the div instead. Or set the p width to a fixed number and put the text overflow rule on that.

Table cells are a bit difficult in this regard, text overflow works with block elements (p, div, etc) in the inline direction. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: I've tried that before, and will try it again, but that doesnt explain the width setting on the td not even being performed.

Comment: You have set the table width to 100% and the table-layout to fixed though.

Answer (score 0):

Move both `overflow: hidden;` and `text-overflow: ellipsis;` from `.table td` to a new rule for `.table td  p`, like

```
.table td {
    width: 120px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.table td p {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Here's the whole thing in a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dJPgNZ